# Android ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm looking for how to implement an expandable list view whose the beginning (e.g 4 first items) is always visible ([ExpandableListView not expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaxrY.png)) and the others items become visible when we expand the list view ([ExpandableListView full expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfZnU.png)).

Do you know a way to do this ?

Comment: You could just change the container height and set animatelayoutchanges to true to get a expanding animation, expandablelistview is not the correct term because android already has it as a view which can expand each itemview in a list.

Comment: Take a look at this awesome tutorial from [android hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) or you could also use this [library](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView) from Github.

For more information see the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Thanks @ChristianStengel it's working